# Codeigniter redirect() does not redirect on some systems

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I do have a CI project in which's home function I check, if a cookie already exists. If so, the user should be redirected. This works fine for example on my linux machine (Chrome), but not on my Mac (Chrome) - and I have no clue why.

This is the code:

```
$session = $this->session->all_userdata();

        if(array_key_exists('id', $session)) {
            redirect(site_url("loggedin"), "refresh");
        } else {
            /* set cookie */
```

Thanks

Comment: And both times you tested the page in Incognito mode to guarantee you had no cookies set?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure if `array_key_exists()` is better or if `isset($_SESSION['id'])` is, but either way CI has this built in with the `session->userdata()` function, which returns `FALSE` if the value isn't set:

```
if($this->session->userdata('session_id'))
    redirect('loggedin',"refresh");

//rest of code
```

Also notice that you don't need `site_url()` in the `redirect()` function.  CI will do that by default.  I'm not sure if any of that has to do with your issue, though.  It could be a browser bug.  Does `redirect('loggedin');` (which would use a location redirect) work?

Comment: Yes, `redirect('loggedin');` works. Oh god, a browser bug? :( I mean, it makes no sense to me, since Chrome for example should be somehow equal on all systems.. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If it works in Safari and Firefox on OSX, then it's definitely a Chrome issue.  Make sure your browser is up to date, and try submitting a bug report.  Also, are you sure you're using Chrome on linux and not Chromium?  Chromium will always be a few builds ahead of Chrome.

Comment: I gave it a try again and now it works... Guess its one of these errors which are very hard to solve :/ Thanks for your help. I'll give you updates on the issue